# Prevent Resharper disabling CodeLens' reference counts

Tags: resharper, codelens

Is there any way to stop Resharper (2012.2.1) disabling the Visual Studio CodeLens reference counts?

Since installing, all reference counts just show:

```
- references | User Name | 1 author, 1 change | 0 incoming changes
```

According the Resharper documentation it gets disabled to speed up VS, and Resharper has its own version activated via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.  However, there doesn't appear to be a way to disable this functionality.  Personally, I still find it useful to glance at the reference counts.

Current settings based on suggestions so far:

[image]

[image]

### Update

I did not renew my Resharper license so am unable to test any further suggestions or solutions.  I'm leaving this post open in the hope that others with the same question might benefit.

Comment: I would update the tags to visual studio  and CodeLens, it's still a current issue

Answer (score 0):

Can be done on the "Performance guide" R# settings page.
[image]

Comment: Is that setting related to the warning guide that pops up at the top when VS starts up?  Changing this option doesn't make any difference for me sadly; CodeLens references are still not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, open `Tools`->`Options...`->`Text Editor`->`All Languages`->`CodeLens` and ensure that it is enabled:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  On VS2017 it is checked, but the "Show References" check box is checked but disabled.  I think Resharper has forced it to be disabled.

Comment: How odd, mine is greyed out but ticked.

Comment: I posted an image in my question above.  Same settings; different results.  Do you see Reference Counts with this setting?

Comment: Have you tried disabling ReSharper to see if it changes its behaviour? Is your VS 2017 fully up to date? The Reference count shows fine in my VS 2019(16.11.2)/ReSharper(2021.2.1). If you think it maybe a ReSharper issue then you could raise a support ticket with Jetbrains.

Comment: The day gets worse... Disabling Resharper causes VS to continuously crash with, "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe..."  I'm not even using that in my solution.  Bug reporting time...

Comment: Time to move to VS2019 or VS2022 then :)

Comment: Yeah I'm waiting for it to go to official release status then I'm in.

Answer (score 0):

Old but I just ran into this frustrating behavior in Visual Studio 2023 recently, that came out of nowhere.

[Reference: Performance Guide for Visual Studio/ReSharper](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/11/30/performance-guide-visual-studio-resharper-2017-3/)

> **Performance Guide settings**

**Notify me** will let ReSharper warn the user about settings that can be changed to improve performance. ReSharper will display the warning in the Notification widget and also in the status bar after a solution has been loaded in Visual Studio.

**Ignore**
will have ReSharper skip changing the option during startup of Visual Studio or when a solution is loaded.

**Fix Silently**
will allow ReSharper to perform performance tuning during Visual Studio startup and when a solution is loaded, without notifying the user through the Notification window or on the status bar.

> **What worked for me**

1. Extensions => ReSharper => Options => Environment -> Performance Guide -> Disable CodeLens for all languages - select "Ignore" - click Apply/Save/Close
2. Tools => Options => Text Editor -> All Languages -> CodeLens - check "EnableCodeLens" - click OK/Close